# Validar el teléfono con expresiones regulares, problemas de SONAR

Tags: java, regex, sonar

En Java, estoy validando el formato del número de teléfono. y lo tengo hecho de esta forma:

```
 public static boolean validaTelefono(String cadena) {
   Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\+[0-9]{11,14}");
   Matcher m = p.matcher(cadena);
   return m.matches();
}
```

Pero cuando paso SONAR a mi aplicación me está dando el siguiente mensaje sobre el compile:

"Using regular expressions is security-sensitive"

Veo cuál es el problema por lo que me sugiere el propio SONAR, pero estoy dando vueltas para solucionarlo y no encuentro la forma correcta sin que SONAR "se queje".

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Tu aplicación va dirigida al entorno web y usa XML por casualidad?

Answer (score 2):

La [documentación de Sonar](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-4784) dice lo siguiente:

> This rule flags any execution of a hardcoded regular expression which has at least 3 characters and at least two instances of any of the following characters: `*+{`

Que viene a ser, en español:

> Esta regla marca cualquier ejecución de una expresión regular literal que tiene al menos 3 caracteres y al menos dos apariciones de los siguiente caracteres: `*+{`

Los motivos para esto son rendimiento, existen ataques que se basan en que el usuario introduce un texto que provoca que la ejecución del *match* necesite varios segundos (una eternidad en tiempos de CPU) para procesarse.

La solución sería hacer la comprobación en dos pasos: Usa una regex más simple para saber que todos los caracteres son un `+` seguido de números, y calcula de manera "manual" la longitud del texto:

```
public static boolean validaTelefono(String cadena) {
    if (cadena.length() > 15 || cadena.length() < 12) { //incluyo el +
        return false;
    }
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\+[0-9]"); //simplificada
    Matcher m = p.matcher(cadena);
    return m.matches();
}
```